# Angular material ng-messages not appearing in dialog

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm creating a log in form in a dialog and ng-messages for the respective input isn't appearing. The validation is working correctly as the input is being highlighted red, and the button is disabled until the validation is correct.

The code for the dialog is is

### Sign in/Create Account

```
        <md-dialog-content>
        <form name="signinForm" id="Signin" class="md-dialog-content">

            <md-input-container class="flex-gt-sm">

                <input type="email" required class="signInText" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" ng-model="signIn.emailAddress"placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="resetPassword.email" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" />
                <div ng-messages="signinForm.emailAddress.$error" role="alert">
                    <div ng-message="pattern">
                        Please enter a valid email address
                    </div>
                </div>

            </md-input-container>
                <br>
                <md-input-container class="flex-gt-sm">

                    <input type="password" class="signInText" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="signIn.password" />

                </md-input-container>
                <br>
                <md-button class= id="resetPassword" style='text-align:center' onClick="resetPassword()">
                    Reset Password
                </md-button>
                <br>
                <!-- Flat button with ripple -->
                <md-checkbox ng-model="signIn.RememberMe" aria-label="Remember Me">
                    Remember Me
                </md-checkbox>
                <br>
                <!-- Flat button with ripple -->
                <md-button class= id="signIn" ng-disabled="signinForm.$invalid" style='text-align:center' ng-click="signIn()">
                    Sign In
                </md-button>
            <md-progress-circular class="md-hue-2 md-busy" ng-show="login.loading" md-mode="indeterminate" style="margin:auto"></md-progress-circular>
        </form>


        </md-dialog-content>
```

This is how I'm creating the dialog box

```
$mdDialog.show({
                controller: signInController,
                templateUrl: 'signIn.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose:true,
            })
```

My module is using ngMessages and if I put the loginform outside of a dialog box then the messages appear correctly.

And I create my controller as a function. There's not much in the controller yet

```
 signInController($scope, $mdDialog, $log) {

}
```

If I put the html outside of a dialog and into a separate page it is working correctly.

I saw this was posted elsewhere

Comment: Can you provide fiddle of the same ? Quiet difficult to debug without that..

Comment: I'm having trouble creating a fiddle with angular material, but there's a site up at searchCollege.me.
The top right button displays a search dialog, which doesn't have the error messages.
The file headerController.js in the scripts/header folder creates the controller. signIn.html is in the main directory

Answer (score 1):

Angular-material 1.1.0-rc has a known [bug](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6399). I noticed that you're using version 1.0.1 and you're probably experiencing the same bug.

The bug shows the **first** error message and then won't display any future error messages, but the field will be highlighted red.

Reproducing the bug in your case:

1. Open the dialog and type an invalid email. It will display the correct error message.
2. Clear the input and blur. Because of the bug, it won't show any future message. In this case it should display the **required** message, but also you didn't specified on. Even if you had specified it won't show.
3. Type again an invalid email. Again, as I said in step 2, it won't display any future error messages.